# Correct sampling methods for this data set / requirements

Tags: data-analysis, sampling

I am just looking for a push in the right direction as to what kind of sampling methods I can use to fulfill this set of sampling criteria. I had thought stratified sampling, but I'm not sure if that's suitable.

Each record contains:

- Visit Id
- Student Id
- Module Id
- Assessor Id

For each visit I need to:

- Sample each module at least once
- Sample each assessor at least once
- Sample a **minimum** of 10% of the students, or 6 , whichever is greater

I also want to be able to add other criteria, such as having a proportional number of male and female students.

Any tips about what I should be looking up would be greatly appreciated! (I haven't done stats in a very long time)